# Xamarin Forms Release Problem: Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.String Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.DateTimeFormatter

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm kinda new to xamarin. I got this error when I'm switching from debug mode to release mode, I search everywhere but I got no answer.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.String Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.DateTimeFormatter::ToRfc1123String(System.DateTimeOffset,System.Boolean)' in assembly: 'Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.InplaceStringBuilder
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedType(TypeReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
       at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.RunTask()
       at Microsoft.Android.Build.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/AndroidTask.cs:line 17"
```

Comment: set "Linking" to "None"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trevor answer worked for me, but there is alternative solution.

I've noticed that this missing class Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.DateTimeFormatter was removed from Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives dll in version 4.0. Some of dependencies to my project required version >=3.2 and some >=5.0. I guess linker chosen to link higher 5.0 version so the other dependency failed to find removed class.

Solution is to update all dependencies so their dependencies uses versions of Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives >=5.0

Answer (score 0):

Turning linking off is the lazy answer. The point of using the linker is to remove "dead" code and minimize the size of the program. The size of a mobile app is more important to many users.

The linker used in Xamarin.Android is going to remove code it thinks you are not using. This is especially true when using reflection. To fix this you would need to tell the compiler you're using the type.

A popular solution is to use a `LinkerPleaseInclude.cs` file and make stub methods using the type and properties so the compiler thinks you're using them. You will find many examples on the Internet.

```cs
public class LinkerPleaseInclude
{
  public void KeepInplaceStringBuilder(Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.InplaceStringBuilder x)
  {
    x.Append('x'); // This will keep the InplaceStringBuilder.Append method from being linked out...
  }
}
```

A newer solution is to use a [Custom Linker Configuration XML file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/linker). This is a bit less of a "hack" than the `LinkerPleaseInclude.cs` solution, but more verbose. It allows you to preserve the whole type, specific methods, properties, etc.

```xml
<linker>
        <assembly fullname="Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers">
                <type fullname="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.InplaceStringBuilder">
        </assembly>
</linker>
```

Either solution will work. Just keep doing this for each of the types the linker complains about and it will eventually work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just deleted some folders like Bin and Obj. Now everything is perfect.