# Xamarin release build fails after adding nlog support for Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-blob-storage, nlog

After adding NLog to our Xamarin forms app with support for the Azure Blob Storage, the Android Release builds fail with the following:

```
Error       Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Void Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AdalAuthenticationContext/<AcquireTokenAsync>d__3::MoveNext()' in assembly: 'Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationResult> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContextIntegratedAuthExtensions::AcquireTokenAsync(Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext,System.String,System.String,Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserCredential)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedMethod(MethodReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.RunTask()
   at Microsoft.Android.Build.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/AndroidTask.cs:line 17  iliidit.Android
```

I've traced it down to the package **NLog.Extensions.AzureBlobStorage** and see that this package has **Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication** as a dependency (which is in the error message!).

I've found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69050534/11269239 which is sort of similar, but a different binary. Have tried to setup the linker file, but can't seem to work it out...

Reading this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/linker
I have tried many combinations, but think this the most precise.

```
<linker>
    <assembly fullname="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory">
        <type fullname="AuthenticationContextIntegratedAuthExtensions">
            <method name="AcquireTokenAsync" />
        </type>
    </assembly>
</linker>
```

And set the **Build Action** to LinkDescription.

I've also tried wildcards.... not sure what I'm doing wrong :(

Comment: Planing to update [NLog.Extensions.AzureBlobStorage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.AzureBlobStorage) to depend on [Azure.Identity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Identity), but still waiting for a working version.

Comment: Thanks @RolfKristensen, do you think this issue will go away once the Nlog extension is moved to Azure.Identity? any ideas on when that might be?

Comment: You can refer to this link(https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/1423).

Answer (score 0):

New updated NLog.Extensions.AzureBlobStorage ver 4.0 has now been released, that switches from legacy AzureServiceTokenProvider to the new Azure.Identity:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.AzureBlobStorage

Hope it will resolve the build issues on the Android-platform